# Pushing my local repository to heroku - all my real "users images" are replaced with test users images?

Tags: image, git, heroku, assets, asset-pipeline

So, my problem is: 
- I have an heroku repository with images from users in "public/assets/.." using the paperclip gem
- I have another local repository with test images like "from users" but it's different.

If i change .gitignore and add "public/assets/*" after a couple of days all my images are gone frome heroku (((

If i delete from "public/assets/*" after pushing my local repository to heroku all my real "users images" will be replaced with test users images.

What should i do to fix this?
thx

Comment: found one tip: public/assets uses in rails 3.1 for generating content from assets:precompile. This is why my comtent was deleted each time when i pushing to heroku. Now just moved to /app/assets/images/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is related, but Heroku has a [read-only filesystem](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem) (although on Cedar you have an [ephemeral filesystem](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-isolation#ephemeral_filesystem)).  Over time, your app may [idle out](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-idling) and move to a different dyno, meaning your tmp folder is clean and clear.  There is no file mirroring between dynos.  This could be why your images seem to dissapear after a couple of days.

If you're using Paperclip / uploaded images at all, you need to look at using something [like S3](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3).